# Rails on a weekend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have been learning/working with Rails for a few weeks now but mostly focused on `ActiveRecord` and its `REST-API` services, `Migrations`, `Routings`, baisc `RSpec` and `FactoryGirl` stuff, etc Didn't do too much on `View` side. But I have a general understanding of it but for example some question like this is still vague to me and I need investigation and learning to find out how to do it:
For example:

> Ok with bootstrap and HAML I create a view for my site, now in the
>   controller I need to be able to know what are the values that user has
>   selected from the View so I can pass them to my service.

Over this weekend wanted to clear out some weak areas so what do you suggest:
The books I have are these:

**1-** Agile Web Dev with Rails: http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails-4

**2-** The Rails View: http://pragprog.com/book/warv/the-rails-view

**3-** Any thing else you suggest?

Comment: @sunny1304 : Yeah I have that too, looked more like a reference book to me, so you suggest that one?

Comment: yes, I suggest that because you can learn about a function without searching much on google, this will save you some time as this book summerizes almost all the common functions and concepts.

Comment: Also, if you are interested in TDD, I found this series of Vidoes quite comprehensive:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ra8Q0M3DJYk

Comment: @WandMaker : Thanks, does he teach it in RSpec syntax?

Comment: Yes, here is alternate link with some info on what each session contains (http://www.rubyfocus.biz/class_video/2010/07/19/rails_tdd_class_1.html)

Comment: I added my comment as answer, so that I will get some points if people like it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in TDD, I found this series of Videos are quite comprehensive:  http://www.rubyfocus.biz/class_video/2010/07/19/rails_tdd_class_1.html

Comment: I am listening to it right now! But my weekend focus I want to cover the weak points I have on understanding how data passes back and forth between View and Controllers.

Answer (score 1):

I know two awesome place to learn Rails

1 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

2 http://railscasts.com/

Check them out ..it will help you

Answer (score 1):

As the author of The Rails View, I'm glad you're giving that a whirl. If you have the print-only edition, there's some errors that are fixed in the PDF. Check the errata. Feel free to ping me as well and I can look at issues. Our book doesn't specifically handle your example, but there's a lot of material in there and we try to tackle a variety of issues. It's Rails 3 specific in some cases.

I'd also suggest Brian Hogan's HTML5 and CSS3 book, which is going into its second edition now. View work is one thing, but a solid foundation in HTML5 and CSS3 are paramount and the building blocks to great views (regardless of ERB vs HAML vs SLIM).

I'm also a subscriber to RailsCasts and Ryan does a great job on various topics there. Peepcode (to which I also subscribe) has some great stuff as well, and finally, if you want to up your Ruby skills, I'd suggest Ruby Tapas from Avdi Grimm.